# Why aren't current CPUs designed for more powerful cooling systems?

Tags: cpu, computers, cooling

Chips on the present can't get smaller, higher speeds and voltages increase heating, so why don't CPU manufacturers aim for more powerful cooling systems instead of looking for parallelization?

We are stuck with a heat sink and a fan since I can remember and yet we have water cooling, heat exchangers and all sort of stuff for cooling computers that are still on the only realm of gaming computers.

Moving this thought forward, if dew point is a problem for moisture why don't we move to anhydrous environments like immersion systems or anhydrous sealed enclousures and then go sub zero?

Comment: who is preventing you from installing a liquid cooling system on a non-gaming computer?

Comment: why do you think that multiple cores are "senseless"? ... what changes do you propose that should be done to one core, instead of adding cores?

Comment: Wrong direction. Water is crappy at removing heat. Requires lots of surface area (hectares of it) and a second, non-water stage if you really want to move heat around. I use direct-expansion R134a fed through high purity, anisotropic thermal-interface, amorphous diamond in \$200\:\mu\text{m}\$ sheets separating the 3D processor stack and removing heat, with directivity to achieve an effective \$131.6\:\frac{\text{W}}{\text{cm}\,\text{K}}\$ thermal conductivity, after necessary routing slots for domain specific adapters and other intra-processor interconnect schemes. Doesn't get any better. ;)

Comment: Because money and complexity matter? Like you said, they are available so why don't *you* buy a monster CPU and put a water cooled refrigerator chilled system on it right now? Whatever reasons you have for not doing that are the reasons why most people don't do it.

Comment: Efficiency significantly reduces with added clock-speeds and single-core performance. I.e. you might get the same heat output and power draw from a 3GHz eight-core and a 6GHz dual-core, but twice the total performance out of the former. Turbo boost is used to somewhat blur between the two options, but in general if you can parallelise the workload it's worthwhile.

Comment: Because Home/Office PCs are meant to be smaller, cozy and cheaper. If you want "more powerful cooling system" with no compromise on performance, simply buy a bulky gaming PC. The product market is flexible. Not everyone cares about "cooling systems".

Comment: @MituRaj, what about server systems then? Or data centers with racks and racks of machines with highly multi-core chips?

Comment: Any question of the form "Why don't they..." can be answered simply, thus: Money.

Comment: @waltinator Don't forget *time*. Usually, one wants to *use* something in their lifetime! (But not always, I suppose.) Besides, all money does is buy the time of others or the products built using the time of others. It's all hanging on a matter of time, really. ;)

Comment: The answer to all *"why don't X product(s) exist"* questions are the same - supply and demand.  There is no value in creating such products because there are not enough people out there who would buy them.  Exotic cooling solutions are expensive and provide only marginal performance benefits.  For almost all users, anything more complicated than a heatsink and a fan is just extra cost with effectively zero benefit.  If you feel this is wrong, you're welcome to put a product on the market and make the gamble of whether or not you'll make your money back.

Answer (score 16):

The surface power density of present day CPU/GPU logic is somewhere between a nuclear reactor rod surface and a rocket nozzle at several W/mm². Caches are being inserted (among other reasons) to reduce average power density.

Present day cooling is already very efficient within the bounds set by silicon's internal heat diffusion capabilities and the silicon-to-something transition on the surface of the chip. This usually means soldered Si-to-metal bonds. You could improve cooling by immersing the whole running system in a liquid (*not a liquid in a copper cooler!*), but performance will rise far less than proportionally to the increased power.

Striving for better parallel computation power and better Perf/W is therefore a much more reasonable or in fact *the only* way forward.

Comment: You can actually improve cooling by immersing it in a liquid; this is called liquid immersion cooling and I know there are people who for *some* reason thought it would be a good idea to fill their bathtub with transformer oil and put their computer in it... It works, it's just an absolute *mess*.

Comment: @Hearth yes it is an efficient way to remove heat. The "somewhat" in my answer was meant with respect to the achievable performance gains. I will make this more clear.

Comment: Mineral oil and a fish tank have also been used, at least in the past. https://www.google.com/search?q=mineral+oil+pc+build

Comment: Related: [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) has a section on the "power wall" being an obstacle for further scaling of single-threaded performance, and of diminishing returns from wider superscalar / out-of-order cores being able to extract more ILP from real programs.

Comment: @PeterCordes One could even argue, that when you do vectorization and SIMD units, you are already entering parallelization terrain and calling this single-threaded performance is becoming a slight stretch. Multi-Core and vector units are just different scopes of parallelization. The ball is in the software side of the pitch currently.

Comment: Oh for sure, data parallelism can be exposed to the CPU at compile time using SIMD *and* thread-level parallelism.  And for a reduction, like the sum of an array, multiple accumulators are needed to hide latency (i.e. expose instruction-level parallelism to the CPU).  That's why a naively-compiled sum of an FP array runs at 1 float per ~5 cycles, but an optimized one can run at 2 vectors per clock on every core.  And with strict-FP semantics, that's not a transformation even a compiler can make automatically.  (It is for integer, though, although scalar integer latency is usually only 1c.)

Comment: But making wider SIMD in a single core, like AVX-512, has some costs (in area and power).  I guess it's an alternative way (compared to cache) of getting more dark silicon, with the option to reduce clock speed and actually use it for a more throughput-optimized operating point.  (Linus Torvalds has called AVX-512 a "power virus", but if power density was too high then the extra area it takes maybe isn't gaining you as much. Although code that can't benefit from SIMD can almost always benefit from cache).

Comment: When it comes to improved heat transfer, I'm waiting for someone to figure out how to grow a single-crystal diamond heatsink directly on the CPU die.

Answer (score 10):

> Chips can't get smaller, higher speeds and voltages increase heating, so why don't cpu manufacturers claim for more powerful cooling systems instead of senselessly adding more cores?

If you look at the performance of high end cooling systems, a major fraction of the total thermal resistance in the system is the silicon to metal junction where the heatsink or water block attaches.  This is true for both air cooling and water cooling and hard to improve.

> Moving this thought even forward, if dew point is a problem for moisture why don't we move to anhydrous environments like immersion systems or anhydrous sealed enclousures and then go sub zero?

There are (very small) communities of people who build sub ambient cooling systems for day to day use (not just benchmarking).  They're very complex and give relatively modest increases in performance.  So yes you can do that if you're interested, but relative to the expense (and the noise of the refrigerant compressor) you won't get much benefit.

Comment: For the issues removing heat from the silicon, you don't need to look at anything unusual. AMD's 5800X is a current mid-high-end CPU which has large issues moving heat out of silicon. With good cooling, in an otherwise similar set-up, a 5900X will be probably 10C cooler. Both draw the same amount of power.

Comment: silicon to metal is a problem, you say? then how about immersing the silicon directly in the cooling fluid?

Comment: @user253751 Direct die cooling is also used occasionally, but has the disadvantage that the coolant must interface to a flat plane rather then a shaped heat exchanger with larger surface area. Results are not markedly better than a well designed silicon to metal to fluid system.

Answer (score 4):

You are making a statement about commodity hardware.  Generally speaking, you have a thermal limit to extract heat from your die.  The fact that most commodity parts are on silicon, means that you are limited by thermal transfer.   In silicon, you have an indirect bandgap so you have a phonon (lattice rattle) when you move charge, and this causes the heat.  Direct-bandgap materials, such that are used in LEDs, do not have this issue.  They still generate heat, but by different physics.

I do a few things as an IC designer in the non-commodity market for heat:

1. I burn more die space, but this costs money.  It's about $0.05USD per mm^2.  This allows me to distribute heat better because I'll place metal to die ties.
2. I will change the substrate to be direct bandgap, such as sapphire or GaS.
3. I will make the system run at a lower voltage to be closer to threshold.

The commodity PC market has probably the worst components from design perspective because they are cheap.  A Si wafer sets me back about $1200USD, and a Sapphire sets be back about $10k.  Si is super cheap, end of reasons to to use it.  For this economic need, you are basically stuck with the thermal transfer limits for the smallest die that does the task that you need done.